# NGINX - Setting a variable with regex replace

Tags: nginx, configuration, nginx-cache

I'm looking to **improve nginx caching by removing irrelevant query parameters** (that could come from web crawlers or similar) from the request. I have come across [an unwieldy solution](https://gist.github.com/a-vasyliev/de8ffc6c6aa74cdeadfe) on the internet:

```
set $c_uri $args; # e.g. "param1=true&param4=false"

# remove unwanted parameters one by one
if ($c_uri ~ (.*)(?:&|^)pd=[^&]*(.*)) { set $c_uri $1$2 ; }
if ($c_uri ~ (.*)(?:&|^)mid=[^&]*(.*)) { set $c_uri $1$2 ; }
if ($c_uri ~ (.*)(?:&|^)ml=[^&]*(.*)) { set $c_uri $1$2 ; }
if ($c_uri ~ (.*)(?:&|^)contact_eid=[^&]*(.*)) { set $c_uri $1$2 ; }
...

set $c_uri $scheme://$host$uri$c_uri;
...

location / {
  # set $c_uri as cache_key
  proxy_cache_key $c_uri;
  ...
}
```

It works, but it's not very concise, takes a lot of steps and from what I learned, [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

I know there are maps, which can do basic regex things but they don't work in this scenario (because there can be any number of parameters in any order that I need to remove).

I also found [this substitution module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/#subs-filter) which can do regex replace but it's only made for specific operations and not for setting a variable.

So I have two questions:

- **Does anyone know whether there is some tooling to set a variable by doing a regex replace operation?**
- **Is using if in this case really that bad?** It's not inside a location context and I don't know whether many consecutive regexes are actually worse than one large regex replace.

I would be very thankful if someone with more nginx know-how could weigh in here and help me out. Thanks :)

Comment: Would it be an option to keep a defined set of args instead of removing unwanted ones?

Comment: "If is Evil... when used in location context" - however, you are not using `if` in a `location` context.

Comment: @slauth sadly no, it's a large application and there are many possible args

Comment: @RichardSmith you are right and thank you for answering my second question. Still, I'm not sure what the performance implications of many if statements are.

Comment: Currently you have a long list of regular expressions, that each need to be evaluated individually for every request. If any or all of the arguments may appear in any request in a random order, then your solution is probably best.

Comment: @MaxKless 1) For removing query arguments from the arguments list I'm using the following regex: `if ($c_uri ~ (.*)(^|&)pd=([^&]*)(\2|$)&?(.*)) { set $c_uri $1$4$5; }` The difference is that on `pd=a&b=c` string yours will give `&b=c` while mine version will give `b=c`. 2) For better performance I recommend to use [`pcre_jit on;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#pcre_jit) if your environment allows it.